# Api определение местоположения пользователя как это сделать с переменной?

Tags: php, html, api

Есть API

```
http://www.site.com/whereami?locale=ru&callback=useriata
```

Ответ:

```
useriata({"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"})
```

И есть ссылка на странице у меня вида

```
http://site.com/flights/?origin_iata=??????????&destination_iata=SPB&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=marker&with_request=true
```

, мне нужно, создать переменную, которая будет равна классу IATA из API и эту переменную вставить заместо ??????? в ссылку. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? Спасибо, с уважением.

Comment: может в ответе все-таки {"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"} ??

Comment: Нет, вот перейдите по ссылке http://www.travelpayouts.com/whereami?callback=useriata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $response = file_get_contents('http://www.travelpayouts.com/whereami?locale=ru&callback=useriata&ip='.$ip);

    preg_match('/\((.+)\)/', $response, $data);

    $data = json_decode($data[1]);
```

ссылка в переменной php:

```
$url = "http://site.com/flights/?origin_iata={$data->iata}&destination_iata=SPB&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=marker&with_request=true";
```

ссылка в html:

```
<a href="http://site.com/flights/?origin_iata=<?=$data->iata?>&destination_iata=SPB&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=marker&with_request=true"></a>
```

Comment: IATA имеет непостоянное значение, у Вас оно =MOW. Значение зависит от местоположения клиента. Или вы имели ввиду вставить ссылку API?

Comment: делаете запрос и обрабатываете полученный ответ

Comment: Не много не понял как.

Comment: обновил ответ с определением по IP

Comment: Дмитрий не работает. Урлы всегда разные но origin_iata зависит от местоположения

Comment: Вот такие у меня ссылки  мне нужно заместо <a href="http://site.com/flights/?origin_iata=????????&destination_iata=SPB&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=marker&with_request=true"><p class="gorod1"><strong>Адамовка</strong></p>

Comment: ссылка которую вы даете определяет ip c которого пришел запрос. В вашем случае это ip вашего сервера. Вы должны определить средствами php ip пользователя и отправить запрос в том виде что я написал в ответе

Comment: Дмитрий мне просто нужно через апи вытащить значение IATA и вставить в ссылку. Спасибо вам за ответ, он правильный, но мне немного нужно другое. Спасибо Вам за ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35329/discussion-between-dmitry-ongamer-and-arcadiy).